# How do I get input from nintendo switch joycons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, joystick, gamepad, nintendo

I'm trying to get input from two Joycons. I have tried joycon-python, but that gives me inaccurate stick movement. I have tried connecting via pybluez, but I can't seem to get anything to work.
So far, the code I have is meant to connect to the joycon.

```
import bluetooth
s = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket()
s.connect("E8:DA:20:A0:22:D0")
```

Preferably I would also like to be able to combine inputs to function as a single controller.

Answer (score 0):

> inaccurate stick movement

[This is why.](https://github.com/tocoteron/joycon-python/blob/master/pyjoycon/joycon.py#L128) Joy-con thumbsticks have some associated calibration data, if you don't calibrate then the analog values will be pretty inaccurate. Looks like `joycon-python` doesn't implement the thumbstick calibration yet.

It's not really that complicated, you could probably add it yourself. Factory calibration data is stored in a block starting at 0x6000, user calibration data is at 0x8000. See [DekuNukem's reverse engineering notes](https://github.com/dekuNukem/Nintendo_Switch_Reverse_Engineering/blob/master/spi_flash_notes.md#analog-stick-factory-and-user-calibration) for instructions on how to read and apply the calibration data.